# Replacing all the elements of a list that are consecutive and duplicates in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, duplicates

Say I have a list with some numbers that are duplicates.

```
list = [1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,1,2,5,6]
```

I want to identify all the elements in the list that are repeating and consecutive, including the first element, i.e. replacing all elements in the list to values in a dictionary:

```
mydict = {1: 'a', 4: 'd'}    
list = ['a','a','a','a',2,3,'d','d',1,2,5,6]
```

Because I want to replace the first instance of the repetition as well, I am quite confused as to how to proceed!

Comment: [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) can help you with this task.

Comment: Side note: **never** name variables after built-ins, e.g. use `lst` or `list_` instead of `list`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is your friend:

```
from itertools import groupby

mydict = {1: 'a', 4: 'd'}
A = [1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,1,2,5,6]

res = []
for k, g in groupby(A):
  size = len(list(g))
  if size > 1:
    res.extend([mydict[k]] * size)  # see note 1
  else:
    res.append(k)
print(res)  # -> ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 2, 3, 'd', 'd', 1, 2, 5, 6]
```

---

Notes:

1. If you want to catch possible `KeyError`s and have a default value you want to *fall back on*, use `mydict.get(k, <default>)` instead of `mydict[k]`